# Optional Argument in cmake macro

Tags: cmake

I want to create a macro whose argument is optional. If not specified, the argument's value should be an empty string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CMake does not (AFAIK) check the number of variables passed to a macro, so you can just go ahead and declare it as any other macro.

There is also a variable `${ARGN}` which expands to a list of all the "remaining" variables passed to a macro, which may be useful.

**Update**
As stated in [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/545974/sam)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346731/optional-argument-in-cmake-macro#comment19554490_1352103), CMake now fails unless all expected (named) arguments are given when calling a macro or function.

Comment: Now cmake does appear to check if too few variable are passed. This answer now appears to be wrong, or at least it is on my cmake 2.8.8

Comment: Your macro can still have optional "arguments" as long as they aren't named in the macro definition. That is, callers are permitted to pass in extra arguments that were not named in the macro's argument list.  Your macro can check for these extra arguments using `${ARGN}`.  Beware: ARGN is not a "normal" cmake variable.  To use it with the list() command, you'll need to copy it into a normal variable first: `set(extra_macro_args ${ARGN})`.  Then you can do things like `list(LENGTH extra_macro_args num_extra_args)` followed by `if( ${num_extra_args} GREATER 0) yadayadayada`

Answer (score 57):

Any arguments *named in your macro definition* are required for callers.  However, your macro can still accept optional arguments as long as they aren't explicitly named in the macro definition.

That is, callers are permitted to pass in **extra** arguments (which were not named in the macro's argument list).  Your macro can check for the existence of such extra arguments by checking the `${ARGN}` variable.

Beware: `ARGN` is not a "normal" cmake variable.  To use it with the `list()` command, you'll need to copy it into a normal variable first:

```cmake
macro (mymacro required_arg1 required_arg2)
    # Cannot use ARGN directly with list() command,
    # so copy it to a variable first.
    set (extra_args ${ARGN})
    
    # Did we get any optional args?
    list(LENGTH extra_args extra_count)
    if (${extra_count} GREATER 0)
        list(GET extra_args 0 optional_arg)
        message ("Got an optional arg: ${optional_arg}")
    endif ()
endmacro (mymacro)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens by default if the argument isn't specified as CMake doesn't check the number of parameters required for a macro.